# Any change in Project properties in Visual Studio Release and Debug Modes?

Tags: visual-studio

Do any of the **project properties**( paths, macros etc) change when you build a project in both **Release** and **`Debug`** mode.Suppose if I set all the project properties for Release mode and now change to Debug mode and build it, do any of the project properties get changed.

All I am aware about is that in Debug build compiler doesn't optimize the code and aids in putting the Debug information.

I strangely have a C++ project which builds fine in Debug mode but gives me some compile time errors in Release mode. I thought these errors should've appeared in Debug mode also.
Not sure what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: I strongly recommend learning how to use [Property Sheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you have to set properties for all your configurations.

When updating the project properties, you can either do it manually for each configurations (Debug/Release) ; or select the "All Configurations" if the property applies to all the configurations.

For example:
If you set new paths in "Additional Include Directories" of the "C/C++" section, you would usually use the same path for all your configurations.

On the other hand, when linking with libraries, you probably have to set the libraries names independently for Debug and Release.